# UWP C# pass a variable to another thread

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Im new to programming, and after 7 days of searching I couldn't find a solution.
My "MainPage" opens, and I click to Open a "SecondaryPage"  which opens on a new thread window with core Dispatcher. My "MainPage" has a button Click event which updates "TextBlock1". What I cant achieve is to pass this value to my "SecondPage" "TextBlock2".

MainPage.xaml below.

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Click="Button_Click_NewWindow" Content="Start a new window" FontSize="30"/>
    <TextBlock Name="Textblock1" Text="Empty" FontSize="30"/>
    <Button Click="Button_Click_Add" Content="+1" FontSize="30"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code Behind SecondPage.xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Name="Textblock2" Text="Empty" FontSize="30"/>
</StackPanel>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace MulitViewV1
{

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public int T1G = 0;


        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Click_NewWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
            int newViewId = 0;
            await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                Frame frame = new Frame();
                frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), null);
                Window.Current.Content = frame;
                // You have to activate the window in order to show it later.
                Window.Current.Activate();

                newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
            });
            bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
        }

       private async void Button_Click_Add(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            T1G = T1G + 1;
            Textblock1.Text = T1G.ToString();

            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                //UI code here
                // NOT WORKING error "TextBlock2" does not exist in the current context
                Textblock2.Text = T1G.ToString();
            });

        }
    }
}
```

I see the Dispatcher is working to my MainPage View, but I cant figure out code to direct it to my SecondPage "newViewID".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Button_Click_NewWindow` where you are calling

```
frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), null);
```

instead of null, pass the text from `TextBlock` like below

```
string TextBoxText = Textblock1.Text;
frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), TextBoxText);
```

And in your `SecondPage`, Override `OnNavigated` to method and you can get the Text like below.

```
string PassedText=e.parameter.ToString();
```

and you can assign this to your `TextBlock` as below

```
Textblock2.Text=PassedText;
```

**Update**

Change your `Button_Click_NewWindow` to below and add the two variables on top.

```
int newViewId = 0;
Window SecondWindow;
private async void Button_Click_NewWindow(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string TextBoxText = Textblock1.Text;
    int mainViewId = ApplicationView.GetApplicationViewIdForWindow(CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow);
    if (newViewId == 0)
    {
        CoreApplicationView newCoreView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
        ApplicationView newAppView = null;
        await newCoreView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            newAppView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
            Window.Current.Content = new Frame();
            (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), TextBoxText);
            Window.Current.Activate();
            SecondWindow = Window.Current;
        });
        newViewId = newAppView.Id;
    }
    else
    {
        await SecondWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            SecondWindow.Content = new Frame();
            (SecondWindow.Content as Frame).Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), TextBoxText);
            SecondWindow.Activate();
        });

    }
    await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId, ViewSizePreference.UseHalf, mainViewId, ViewSizePreference.UseHalf);
}
```

And your output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me, I'm getting there.On my Button_Click_NewWindow, it opens a second window. code : :frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), T1G); and passes the variable.  Then my Button_Click_Add, how do I pass the new update variable to the second opened window?

Comment: I cant thank you enough, I've been stuck for a week trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to call `Dispatcher` all the time. You button clicks are coming to you on the UI thread so the handlers are also going to be on the UI thread.

A way to think about it is that you're always on the UI thread unless you're doing something with `*Async`. If you await async stuff, you're good. This is not true all of the time, but it's a place to start and handle the problems you might encounter as the come.

Generally you only want a single `Frame` in your application. Multiple `Frames` (and multiple windows) is an advanced topic; save it for later.

By default, you UWP app will contain a `Frame`. Pages are hosted in this frame. The frame can navigate between the pages it hosts. Think of the frame as you browser window, and the pages are like web pages.

You can get the `Frame` by getting the `Frame` property on the page. To navigate to a new page you do this:

```
private async void Button_Click_NewWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), null);
}
```

Next you want to change the text of `TextBlock2`. `TextBlock2` is located on `SecondPage`, but your code is in `MainPage`, which has no `TextBlock2`, and the compiler is telling you that `TextBlock2` isn't a thing in `MainPage`.

Inside your `SecondPage.xaml.cs` you are however able to get to `TextBlock2` as it is present there. Remember though, `MainPage` will not be visible after navigation to `SecondPage` (just as you can't see two web pages at the same time when navigating from one to another).